# Combine a list with a list of varied length within a list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am trying to combine historical data, which comes from an ancient custom made email system, to create a database with Python. One list (`b`) contains the email id, and another list (`a`) contains filenames of attachments. An email may have zero, one, or many attachments. There are thousands of records to process.

I have extracted the data in the following format:

```
a = [[], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
b = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

I want the empty data in 'a' removed and the remaining data in the following format, but don't care if it is a list or tuple.

```
x = [[['c2', 'a'], [['c3', 'b'], ['c3', 'c'], ['c4', 'd']]]
```

I have tried using zip

```
x = zip(b, a)
```

But that added to the start of each

```
(('c1', []), ('c2', ['a']), ('c3', ['b', 'c', 'd']))
```

I tried itertools chain:

```
op = [list(itertools.chain(*i))
      for i in zip(b, a)]
```

But that yielded:

```
[['c', '1'], ['c', '2', 'a'], ['c', '3', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

I have also tried using `re.findall()` to get the data into a more usable format, but there will usually be a mismatched number of email ids to filenames. There is lots of stuff about lists and joining, etc., but I haven't found anything useful regarding a list within a list where there is variable length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right (in your output you have `c4` but I think it should be `c3`):

```py
a = [[], ["a"], ["b", "c", "d"]]
b = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]

out = [[[v, s] for s in l] for v, l in [t for t in zip(b, a) if t[1]]]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[["c2", "a"]], [["c3", "b"], ["c3", "c"], ["c3", "d"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With meaningful names (and without Andrej's inexplicable extra comprehension ;-):

```
attachment_lists = [[], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
emails = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

result = [[[email, attachment] for attachment in attachments]
          for email, attachments in zip(emails, attachment_lists)
          if attachments]

print(result)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU7LCsMgELz7FXvbBLy0ufTSLxEpNjVkwRjR7SH9eYsKraV7mGWYBxMOXnc/XULM2TCbed2s55ujxAmuoJSWoNBgfXeUgHOBB2ot7GbIVRfOpyqdK06ohYg2PR3XClWNEr79GpY9dhzIdyxpAZ8rxr98KoEXhaFN6KU2fewaaPntFiGS56ENHHN@Aw)):

```
[[['c2', 'a']], [['c3', 'b'], ['c3', 'c'], ['c3', 'd']]]
```