# Combine a simple list with a list of a varied number of dual elements

Tags: python, list

I am trying to collect information from an ancient email system. I need to join an email id with the receiver information. Each email will have one or more receivers and be either "to", "cc", or "bcc". The data is in the following format:

```
em_id = ['e1', 'e2']
rec = [[['To', 'Bob'], ['To', 'Billy'], ['Cc', 'Jane']], [['Bcc', 'Bob']]]]
```

I need the result to be like `['id', 'to', 'name']` such as:

```
em_rec = [['e1', 'To', 'Bob'], ['e1', 'To', 'Billy'], ['e1', 'Cc', 'Jane'], ['e2', 'Bcc', 'Bob']]
```

I can work out how to insert one, but not how to loop it, particularly because the loop length varies for every record.

I asked a similar question that used zip at [Combine a list with a list of varied length within a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390180/combine-a-list-with-a-list-of-varied-length-within-a-list) and the answer was awesome. I suspect the answer will be similar but this one needs 3 values per list item and has no empty cases.

Answer (score 1):

```py
em_rec = [['e1' if condition(r) else 'e2'] + r for r in rec]
```

Comment: Will this work with the thousands of records?

Comment: if em_id contains only 2 values ('e1' and 'e2') then yes it will. But if it contains many more ids you could change it to  `em_rec = [[em_id[get_id(r)]] + r for r in rec]` where get_id(r) returns the index of the em_id

Comment: @ananta If it doesn't have the same amount of values, check out the **Edit:** part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
>>> [[[x] + i for i in y] for x, y in zip(em_id, rec)]
[[['e1', 'To', 'Bob'], ['e1', 'To', 'Billy'], ['e1', 'Cc', 'Jane']], [['e2', 'Bcc', 'Bob']]]
>>>
```

Or unpacking:

```
[[[x, *i] for i in y] for x, y in zip(em_id, rec)]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to repeat `em_id`:

```
from itertools import cycle
[[[x] + i for i in y] for x, y in zip(cycle(em_id), rec)]
```

Comment: Thankyou. They almost work, but the output is a list within a list within a list, rather than a list within a list.